# Managing the style in the Atlas in QGIS

Tags: qgis, atlas, style-manager

Is there a setting in Atlas to manage the style of the printed item?

I use Atlas in a network, each item is in the center of the image, but there are many items near this one and I need to highlight only this one.
I have to use a variable scale.

I use QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a **rule-based symbology** using a test to check whether the current feature is the atlas feature or not :

Rule 1 : Test - `$id=$atlasfeatureid`

Define and Apply the style for atlas feature

Rule 2 : Test - `$id<>$atlasfeatureid`

Define and apply the style for 'other' features

You're able to add some transparency to the non-atlas features to make the atlas feature pop up a bit more (for example)

*Look in the previous questions this has been asked very often.*